# ggplot font size for different elements

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know that after I create a ggplot graph I can use `theme_get()` to return detail of all the theme elements. This has been very helpful in figuring out things like `strip.text.x` and the like. But I have two things I can't figure out:

1) In the following ggplot graphic, what is the name of the theme item representing the phrase "Percent of wood chucked by the woodchuck" as I want to resize it to a larger font:

[image]

2) How do I reformat the y axis labels to read 10%, 20, ... instead of .1, .2, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For (2) what you want is to use a `formatter`:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10)

#For ggplot2 0.8.9    
ggplot(dat,aes(x = x/10,y=y/10)) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_continuous(formatter = "percent")

#For ggplot2 0.9.0    
ggplot(dat,aes(x = x/10,y=y/10)) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

For 1), it is `$axis.title.y`

```
p + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 25))
```

where `p` is an existing ggplot object.

I don't know about 2) off hand.