# Left-align tick mark labels in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I can find options to align the legend and axis labels in `ggplot`, but not for the tick mark labels.

Is it possible to have those labels not right-aligned to the graph plot-box, but left-aligned flush with either the start of the longest label, or some set distance from the overall graph-border?

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
library(ggplot2)
axisLabels.x <- c("This is a longer label", 
              "Short label", "Short label","Short label","Short label",
              "This is again a longer label")
labels.wrap  <- lapply(strwrap(axisLabels.x,50,simplify=F),paste,collapse="\n") # word wrap
gg <- data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:6], y=sample(1:10,6))
ggplot(gg) +
  geom_bar(aes(x,y, fill=x), stat="identity")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=labels.wrap)+
  scale_fill_discrete(guide="none")+
  labs(x="",y="Response")+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

---

Wanted:

[image]

Comment: `theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=0))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [changing font size and direction of axes text in ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297995/changing-font-size-and-direction-of-axes-text-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As it provides the solution, I make @user20650's comment an answer.

```
set.seed(1)
library(ggplot2)
axisLabels.x <- c("This is a longer label", 
                  "Short label", "Short label","Short label","Short label",
                  "This is again a longer label")
labels.wrap  <- lapply(strwrap(axisLabels.x,50,simplify=F),paste,collapse="\n") # word wrap
gg <- data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:6], y=sample(1:10,6))
plot <- ggplot(gg) +
  geom_bar(aes(x,y, fill=x), stat="identity")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=labels.wrap)+
  scale_fill_discrete(guide="none")+
  labs(x="",y="Response")+
  coord_flip()
```

**And here we go**

```
plot + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

[image: left aligned y scale labels]