# Need help fixing axis labels, texts too long

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need help with my plot, I am using 56 airlines in the X axis and there is not enough room how can you fix this?

```
ggplot(airline_safety, aes(x=airline ,y=incidents_85_99)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: See [this question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297995/changing-font-size-and-direction-of-axes-text-in-ggplot2)

Comment: ^Agreed, flagged as duplicate.