# Change axis text direction to right-to-left

Tags: r, ggplot2, arabic, right-to-left, hebrew

In right-to-left languages such as Arabic and Hebrew, how can I adjust the direction of text for `ggplot2` text elements?
Note that I'm not talking about alignment (which is controlled by the `hjust`, but rather the actual direction (the equivalent to CSS `direction: rtl;`) in which the text is rendered. 
Hence, this is not a replication of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297995/changing-font-size-and-direction-of-axes-text-in-ggplot2).

Here is a min reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

example1 <- tribble(
  ~item,
  "האם יורד גשם?"
)

# or as ordinary data frame, to avoid 'tibble' dependency
example1 <- data.frame(item = "האם יורד גשם?")

ggplot(example1, aes(item)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 25))
```

I have enlarged the axis text x to illustrate what I mean.
The code produces the following chart, note that the question mark is on the right side of the text and I want it to appear on the left side of the text. In the tibble `example1` it's ok (even though it looks "opposite", the question mark ends the sentence.)

[image: Change direction of element_text]

Comment: theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 25, angle = -180)) ?

Comment: Slightly related: there is currently a [WIP pull request for RtL plotting on Github](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/2817) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the Unicode control character for "RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING" ("Treat the following text as embedded right-to-left"): `u202B`. See [Explicit Directional Embeddings](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Explicit_Directional_Embeddings).

```
example1$item <- paste("\u202B", example1$item)
ggplot(example1, aes(item)) + 
   geom_bar() +
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 25))
```

[image]

Comment: AMAZING!, I'm utterly impressed. I didn't imagine it was that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the question mark in the original, and then it comes out ok:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
example1 <- tribble(
  ~item,
  "?האם יורד גשם"
)

ggplot(example1, aes(item)) + 
geom_bar() + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 25))
```

Comment: Hi Omry, this answer is a workaround that only solves the problem in the simple case you have a simple line. Imagine having a big data file with Hebrew characters, perhaps utilizing a text wrap, i.e., with `str_wrap` and the wrap yields other punctuation marks (-,.?!, etc.) in other lines... This makes this workaround less practical.